# Attempting to create something using dictionaries but am lost

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm not really too sure how to best approach the following in python...
I know what I want, and have an idea of how I want it, but I don't know if my idea is the best approach to what I'm looking for.

```
"Name":"path",contains[]
"Folder":"C:/blah/blah/folder",contains["file1","file2","file3"]
```

like

```
things={}
things["Folder"]="C:/blah/blah/folder" AND contains["file1","file2","file3"]
```

so that it can be used like:

```
for folder,path,contents in things.iteritems():  
    print("%s @ \"%s\" containing:\n\t")%(folder,path)  
    for file in contents:  
        print("%s\n\t")%(file)
```

and how could I add things to contents, something like

```
content.append(blah)
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Cleaned up your post but it's still not really clear at all what you're looking for.  The first two blocks aren't really valid code so it's unclear what they mean.  Explain more of what you want to happen rather than posting stuff that looks like code but isn't.

Comment: `content[key] = value` http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Are you thinking something like the os.walk function?

Comment: @Winston: trying to make something that I can use for more than traversing a directory.

Comment: @Daniel: thanks for the cleanup, still getting used to this. The top was something that wasnt meant to be compiled, just trying to lay out the idea of what I wanted. I have some understanding of dictionaries, but dont know how I could store a value and an array at the same time in a dictionary. The last 2 things are what Im trying to achieve overall. Im not even sure using a dictionary format is what would be best.

Comment: This is probably the most difficult-to-understand question I've seen posted on stackoverflow. Please state your question more clearly, and lots of people would be very willing to help.

Comment: @blokeley: Kinda difficult when you arent too sure how to word what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d["Folder"] = ["C:/blah/blah/Folder", ["file1","file2","file3"]]
>>> d["more"] = ["/home/mydir", ["file1","file2","file3"]]
>>> d["Folder"][0]
'C:/blah/blah/Folder'
>>> d["Folder"][1]
['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
>>> d["Folder"][1].append("file4")
>>> d["Folder"][1]
['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4']
>>> for entry in d:
...     d[entry][1].append("newfile")
...
>>> d
{'Folder': ['C:/blah/blah/Folder', ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4', 'newfile']],
 'more': ['/home/mydir', ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'newfile']]}
```

Comment: +1 for showing a complete, interactive example. (The REPL is a great learning tool.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a nested dictionary:

```
things = {"Folder" : {"path" : "C:/blah/folder", "contents" : ["file1", "file2"]},
          "Directory" : {"path" :"C:/foo/dir", "contents" : ["fileX", "fileY"]}}
for folder, info in things.iteritems():
  print("%s @\"%s\" containing:\n\t")%(folder, info["path"])
  for file in info["contents"]:
    print("%s\n\t")%(file)
```

Comment: I think you are right, on to a little bit of toying, I shall return, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
things = {}
things["Folder"] = ("C:/blah/blah/folder", ["file1","file2","file3"])

for folder, (path, contents) in things.iteritems():
    print("%s @ \"%s\" containing:\n\t")%(folder,path)  
    for file in contents:  
        print("%s\n\t")%(file)
```